# JSON Parsing of JSON Objects in android

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON like,

```
 {

 "Area1": "areacode1",
 "Area2": "areacode2",
 "Area3" : "areacode3"

 }
```

I want to parse the json and iterate "area" it to autocompletetextview,
 My code is,

//Reading JSON from local file

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("arealist.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");



    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

//parsing and iterating the json...

```
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
           Iterator<String> keys= obj.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext())
        {
            String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
            String valueString = obj.getString(keyValue);
            Log.d("Details-->",valueString);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting the error as "Type mismatch:can't convert JSONObject to JSONArray",I want to know how to convert JSONObject to string and iterate to List.I am new to android so confused how to proceed further 
Kindly help,Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure your json return this response  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to read arealist.json like this

```
InputStream inputStream = getContext().getAssets().open("arealist.json");
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));


 String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            //parse JSON and store it in the list
            String jsonString =  sb.toString();
```

and use this jsonString in JSONobject

Answer (score 0):

After debug the given json by the below code:

```
    String json = "{\n" +
            "\n" +
            " \"Area1\": \"areacode1\",\n" +
            "  \"Area2\": \"areacode2\",\n" +
            "  \"Area3\" : \"areacode3\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            " }";
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        Iterator<String> keys= obj.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext())
        {
            String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
            String valueString = obj.getString(keyValue);
            Log.d("Details-->",valueString);
        }



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I realize that the way you read which json does not have any problem. The problem is the string return from `loadJSONFromAsset`. You must correct the out of that method.